# When you add a new mongodb replica, how do you know when it has caught up to the master?

Tags: mongodb, database-replication

If you add a new replica to mongodb, how do you know if it has caught up to the master node or at least the other replicas?

Do you add this new replica to your mongodb clients to query from or this will cause issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you add a new replica to mongodb, how do you know if it has caught
>   up to the master node or at least the other replicas?

From the documentation [Add Members to a Replica Set](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expand-replica-set/):

> Ensure that the new member has reached SECONDARY state. To check the
>   state of the replica set members, run rs.status().

Also see various [replica set status](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/replSetGetStatus/#output).

> Do you add this new replica to your mongodb clients to query from or
>   this will cause issues?

Clients connect to a replica set. By default all read and write operations go to the primary member. Your replica set can be configured such that the read operations can be directed to secondaries - by setting the [Read Preference](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/read-preference/).

You don't need to do any specific configuration to tell the cilent programs to access the new member of the replica set.

Comment: oh so the clients will find out about the new replica by itself?  b/c in the connection string I see it takes an array of ip addresses of the servers.

Comment: Drivers will not send operations to a RS node that is still initializing (not a primary or a secondary). Drivers also will discover all RS nodes when they connect to any of the nodes.

Comment: Also, see the sub-topic **Discovery** in this post [Server Discovery and Monitoring In Next Generation MongoDB Drivers](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/server-discovery-and-monitoring-next-generation-mongodb-drivers).